# Python: LOAD_FAST vs. LOAD_DEREF with inplace addition

Tags: python, closures, bytecode

Last Friday I went to a job interview and had to answer the following question: why does this code raise an exception (`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment` on the line containing `var += 1`)?

```
def outer():
    var = 1

    def inner():
        var += 1
        return var

    return inner
```

I couldn't give a proper answer; this fact really upset me, and when I came home I tried really hard to find a proper answer. Well, I *have* found the answer, but now there's something else that confuses me.

**I have to say in advance** that my question is more about the decisions made when designing the language, not about how it works.

So, consider this code. The inner function is a python closure, and `var` is not local for `outer` - it is stored in a cell (and then retrieved from a cell):

```
def outer():
    var = 1

    def inner():
        return var

    return inner
```

The disassembly looks like this:

```
0  LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
3  STORE_DEREF              0 (var)  # not STORE_FAST

6  LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (var)
9  BUILD_TUPLE              1
12 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object inner at 0x10796c810)
15 LOAD_CONST               3 ('outer.<locals>.inner')
18 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
21 STORE_FAST               0 (inner)

24 LOAD_FAST                0 (inner)
27 RETURN_VALUE

recursing into <code object inner at 0x10796c810:

0  LOAD_DEREF               0 (var)  # same thing
3  RETURN_VALUE
```

This changes when we try to bind something else to `var` inside the inner function:

```
def outer():
    var = 1

    def inner():
        var = 2
        return var

    return inner
```

Yet again the disassembly:

```
0  LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
3  STORE_FAST               0 (var)  # this one changed
6  LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object inner at 0x1084a1810)
9  LOAD_CONST               3 ('outer.<locals>.inner')
12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0  # AND not MAKE_CLOSURE
15 STORE_FAST               1 (inner)

18 LOAD_FAST                1 (inner)
21 RETURN_VALUE

recursing into <code object inner at 0x1084a1810:

0  LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
3  STORE_FAST               0 (var)  # 'var' is supposed to be local

6  LOAD_FAST                0 (var)  
9  RETURN_VALUE
```

We store `var` locally, which complies to what is said in the documentation: *assignments to names always go into the innermost scope*.

Now, when we try to make an increment `var += 1`, a nasty `LOAD_FAST` shows up, which tries to get `var` from `inner`'s local scope:

```
14 LOAD_FAST                0 (var)
17 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
20 INPLACE_ADD
21 STORE_FAST               0 (var)
```

And of course we get an error. Now, *here is what I don't get*: why can't we retrieve `var` with a `LOAD_DEREF`, and THEN store it inside `inner`'s scope with a `STORE_FAST`? I mean, this seems to be O.K. with the "innermost scope" assignment stuff, and in the same time it's somewhat more intuitively desirable. At least the `+=` code would do what we want it to do, and I can't come up with a situation in which the described approach could mess something up.

Can you? I feel that I'm missing something here.

Comment: Do you really think it's intuitively desirable that `var += 1` should copy the closure variable instead of mutating it? Because for me, if this did compile, it's the latter I'd be expecting (and desiring).

Comment: I see your point. My initial motivation was that if you, say, tried to `print(var)` before incrementing, you would still get an `UnboundLocalError` and nothing will be printed. So you don't get a chance to do something to this variable even *before* you make up you mind to `+=`.
Although I do understand that this is more about "user's" perspective.

Comment: I see what you're thinking. But basically, Python thinks of the whole scope as something you "make up your mind" to write at once, not as something you write "stream-of-consciousness" style. So, you've already decided that you want a local variable when you do the `print(var)`, even if that local variable isn't bound to anything yet. Maybe the clearest alternative would just be a different error saying that there _is_ no local variable `var` yet, rather than that there is one but it's "unbound", which only really makes sense if you think about what happens under the covers…

Comment: If you *only* print a non-local variable, it will work fine. If you first print and then modify it, you would either be silently modifying a global, or suddenly switching the meaning of `var` from non-local to local. Neither of these seems like a good design choice.

Comment: I guess I'm convinced now that current implementation is the correct one. :)

Comment: What does "why can't we" **mean**? Is this question about the rules Python follows in order to compile the code? Or about the design decision behind those rules? Or **just what**?

Comment: Alternatively: the reason why we "can't retrieve var with a LOAD_DEREF, and THEN store it inside inner's scope with a STORE_FAST" is that `LOAD_DEREF` means to load from a different place from where `STORE_FAST` stores.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python has a very simple rule that assigns each name in a scope to exactly one category: local, enclosing, or global/builtin.

(CPython, of course, implements that rule by using FAST locals, DEREF closure cells, and NAME or GLOBAL lookups.)

---

Your changed rule does make sense for your dead-simple case, but it's easy to come up with cases where it would be ambiguous (at least for a human reader, if not for the compiler). For example:

```
def outer():
    var = 1

    def inner():
        if spam:
            var = 1
        var += 1
        return var

    return inner
```

Does that `var += 1` do a `LOAD_DEREF` or `LOAD_FAST`? We can't know until we know the value of `spam` at runtime. Which means we can't compile the function body.

---

Even if you could come up with a more complicated rule that makes sense, there's virtue inherent in the rule being simple. Besides being easy to implement (and therefore easy to debug, optimize, etc.), it's easy for someone to understand. When you get an `UnboundLocalError`, any intermediate-level Python programmer knows how to work through the rule in his head and figure out what went wrong.

---

Meanwhile, notice that when this comes up in real-life code, there are very easy ways to work around it explicitly. For example:

```
def inner():
    lvar = var + 1
    return lvar
```

You wanted to load the closure variable, and assign to a local variable. There's no reason they need to have the same name. In fact, using the same name is misleading, even with your new rule—it implies to the reader that you're modifying the closure variable, when you really aren't. So just give them different names, and the problem goes away.

And that still works with the nonlocal assignment:

```
def inner():
    nonlocal var
    if spam:
        var = 1
    lvar = var + 1
    return lvar
```

Or, of course, there are tricks like using a parameter default value to create a local that starts off with a copy of the closure variable:

```
def inner(var=var):
    var += 1
    return var
```

Comment: Yes, sure, I knew about the `nonlocal` trick. And it seems like your answer is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @oopcode: Something like your design _could_ make sense for a different language. The obvious one is to make variables nonlocal by default and require you to explicitly declare them local. Then you get the question of whether to include global in the lookup, like JavaScript, or make globals special, like Scheme. Either one works, but both feel very different from Python.

Answer (score 3):

Are you making it too hard? `var` cannot be local because it's being dereferenced before assignment, and it cannot be non-local (unless declared `global` or `nonlocal`) because it's being assigned to.

The language is designed this way so that (a) you don't accidentally stomp on global variables: Assigning to a variable makes it local unless you explicitly declare it `global` or `nonlocal`. And (b) you can easily *use* the values of variables in outer scopes. If you dereference a name you haven't defined locally, it looks for it in enclosing scopes.

Your code must dereference the variable before it can increment it, so the rules of the language make the variable both local and non-local--a contradiction. The result: Your code will only run if you declare `var` to be `nonlocal`.

Comment: No, I didn't intend to return `inner()`. The examples are base upon this article: http://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/06/05/pythons-innards-naming/

Comment: This seems like it's on track to be the right answer. Globals aren't an issue here; it's local variables vs. closure variables. But it's the same thing: `var` can't be a nonlocal if it's a local.

Comment: Yet again, I seem to understand *why* this doesn't work (the disassembly shows it quite clear), I'm not sure about why is was designed to work this way.

Comment: I expanded on the motivation a little, and made it specific to your closure context. (The reasons are exactly the same as with `global`, but you need `nonlocal` here of course).

Answer (score 0):

You're digging too deep. This is an issue of the language semantics, not opcodes and cells. `inner` contains an assignment to the name `var`:

```
def inner():
    var += 1    # here
    return(var)
```

so by the Python execution model, `inner` has a local variable named `var`, and all attempts to read and write the name `var` inside `inner` use the local variable. While Python could have been designed so that if the local `var` isn't bound, it tries the closure's `var`, Python wasn't designed that way.

Comment: I think he's asking why the Python execution model was designed that way, instead of a different way.