# Get the input of an Higher order function in python

Tags: python, function, input, arguments, higher-order-functions

Let's say I have a HOF

```
def some_func(lst):
    def func(args):
        if args[0]=='compute':
            return sum(lst)
        elif args[0]=='add':
            XXXXX  #Return a new HOF with the 2 sub HOF input parameters added together.  
    return func
x1=some_func([1,2,3])
x2=some_func([2,3,4])
```

One of the input *args for HOF is `('add', another_hof)`, which require the HOF to add another HOF parameter and return a HOF with added parameter.

example:

```
x3=x1('add',x2)
x4=some_func([3,5,7])
```

Then,

```
x3 should equal x4.
test_case: 
x1=some_func([1,2,3])
x2=some_func([2,3,4])
x1('compute')=6
x2('compute')=9
x3=x1('add',x2)
x3('compute')=15
```

When I am doingx HOF the ('add,x2) for x1 function, is possible me to know the x2' input parameter [2,3,4] inside the function func(*args)?

Comment: ... Wouldn't you be able to access it within `func` by using the name `lst`? Doesn't seem any different than accessing any other variable.

Comment: Did you try `print(lst)` inside `func`? I guess not. This is not different than any other nested function or decorator

Comment: Forgive my poor english. Trying to ask is it possible for me to know HOF x2 parameter when I am doing 'add' for x1

Comment: You can access `lst` inside `func`, as long as you don't attempt to assign to the name `lst` in there, since that will tell Python to treat that name as a local of `func`. If `lst` is an actual `list` then it's safe to _mutate_ it, though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157655/python-load-fast-vs-load-deref-with-inplace-addition for details.

Comment: If we're not understanding your actual question then you need to add some more code to your question that more closely illustrates what you want to do. All this HOF talk is a bit confusing: it's a bit hard to keep track of which HOF is which. ;)

Comment: Please edit your question so someone else than you have at least a chance to understand what you're trying to do. Also, remember that you can define your own callable objects (python functions are objects...) which provide the same overall features as HOFs/closures but make state management much easier. Quite a few decorators (one of Python's most well-known use of HOFs) are actually implemented as callable classes instead of functions.

Comment: Edited...hope this time it looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, the core of the problem is: given a reference to a `func` instance, you need to get the `lst` value that it contains.

One way to do this is to add another mode to your conditional block that returns `lst`. Let's call it `get_lst`:

```
def some_func(lst):
    def func(*args):
        if args[0]=='compute':
            return sum(lst)
        elif args[0]=='add':
            new_lst = [a+b for a,b in zip(lst, args[1]("get_lst"))]
            return some_func(new_lst)
        elif args[0] == "get_lst":
            return lst
    return func

x1=some_func([1,2,3])
x2=some_func([2,3,4])
print(x1('compute'))
print(x2('compute'))
x3=x1('add',x2)
print(x3('compute'))
```

Result:

```
6
9
15
```

You could also assign `lst` to an attribute of the function object:

```
def some_func(lst):
    def func(*args):
        if args[0]=='compute':
            return sum(lst)
        elif args[0]=='add':
            new_lst = [a+b for a,b in zip(lst, args[1].params)]
            return some_func(new_lst)
    func.params = lst
    return func

x1=some_func([1,2,3])
x2=some_func([2,3,4])
print(x1('compute'))
print(x2('compute'))
x3=x1('add',x2)
print(x3('compute'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, never thought that I can add one conditional block. Thanks so much!