# local variable referenced before assignment (list)

Tags: python-3.x

I encountered an interesting error. When defining a list outside the scope of a function, like below, it causes an error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`

```
def main():
    a = []
    
    def sub():
        a += ["hello"]
        return a 
    sub()
main()
```

However, with the same logic, if used `a.append` no error is raised

```
def main():
    a = []
    
    def sub():
        a.append("hello")
        return a 
    sub()
main()
```

Is there any reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Python increment variable in closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959985/why-cant-python-increment-variable-in-closure)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `nonlocal` keyword in this case.
[nonlocal documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)

```
def main():
    a = []
    
    def sub():
        nonlocal a
        a += ["hello"]
        return a 
    sub()
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the python bytecode that is generated.
For this portion.

```
from dis import dis

def main():
    a = []
    
    def sub():
        a.append(['hello'])
        return a 
    print(dis(sub))
    sub()
main()
```

OUTPUT

```
  8           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (append)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              8 CALL_METHOD              1
             10 POP_TOP

 10          12 LOAD_DEREF               0 (a)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see we are loading a reference of `a` the list to the function using `LOAD_DEREF`. While on

```
from dis import dis

def main():
    a = []
    
    def sub():
        a += ["hello"]
        return a 
    print(dis(sub))
    sub()
main()
```

OUTPUT

```
  9           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              4 BUILD_LIST               1
              6 INPLACE_ADD
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 10          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

we try to load a local variable `a` into memory and we use a `LOAD_FAST` instruction. That is why there is an error. If you use `nonlocal` variable. You would load the variable with `LOAD_DEREF`.

Also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157655/python-load-fast-vs-load-deref-with-inplace-addition) for why we do so.